# I got errors when I install drivers for opencl and Amd gpu with amdgpu-install in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, amdgpu, opencl, davinci-resolve

To use Davinci Resolve 18. I have to install some drivers.

My Graphic card(amd radeon-620) - AMD® Hainan / Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)

I install amdgpu-install

```
   amdgpu-install
```

Here's my errors.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 rocm-llvm : Depends: libstdc++-5-dev but it is not installable or
                      libstdc++-7-dev but it is not installable
             Depends: libgcc-5-dev but it is not installable or
                      libgcc-7-dev but it is not installable
             Recommends: gcc-multilib but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: g++-multilib but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu : Depends: xorg-video-abi-24
```

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Drivers for AMD graphics are already installed and running, no user action required. The proprietary overlay you tried to install is not (yet) updated for your release, hence the dependencies errors.

Comment: so, what can i do davinci resolve to work on my ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

After installing below package, Davinci Resolve works

```
sudo apt-get install -y mesa-opencl-icd
```

Comment: Does it work for you? It worked fine with 22.04 but after a few weeks every video i import is blank. I convert my videos to DNxHD (.mov). Same videos work fine with davinci resolve on fedora and arch, but on ubuntu nothing. I had the same problem with ubuntu 21.04, 21.10, 22.04 after a few weeks and i installed a clean 22.10 yesterday...with no luck. So yes, after installing opencl-icd , the program starts and everything seems ok but you can't import anything. If it works ok for you please let us know